# Iphone static libraries problem

Tags: iphone

Hello i am making an static library for distribution.
I am distributing the .h files and the .a file.
The problem is that if there is a runtime error, the debugger is able to see the content of the .m files. How can i avoid that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compile it as release mode and strip all the debug symbols.

Comment: And how would i do that?
I am checking "Deployment Postprocessing" and "Strip linked Product" but i am still able to see the code when debugging. Am i missing something else?

Comment: @pabloruiz: Try to "Use Separate Strip". Also, are you checking in a different project (you should)?